# Split a 24 X 24 matrix in 5 X 5 matrixes to get all possible combinations of rows and columns in R

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

I need to split a 24 X 24 dataframe in 5 X 5 dataframes where all possible combinations of rows and columns from the original 24 X 24 dataframe are included. Anyone up for the task?

Comment: You may consider `expand.grid()` or `tidyr::complete`.

Comment: There are 42504 combinations of 24 columns 5 by 5. Times an equal number of combinations of 24 rows 5 by 5 that's 1806590016 matrices. Each with 5*5 elements. If they are of class `"integer"` (32 bits), you'll need 168.2518 GB to store the result. Care to reformulate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are 42504 combinations of 24 columns 5 by 5. Times an equal number of combinations of 24 rows 5 by 5 that's 1806590016 matrices. Each with 5*5 elements. If they are of class "integer" (32 bits), you'll need 168.2518 GB to store the result.

```
choose(24, 5)^2 * 5^2 * 4 / 1024/1024/1024
#[1] 168.2518
```

If this is really needed, here is a function to create sub-data.frames or sub-matrices where all possible combinations of rows and columns from the original data.frame or matrix are included.

```
sub_df <- function(x, n, output = c("data.frame", "matrix")){
  nr <- nrow(x)
  nc <- ncol(x)
  out <- match.arg(output)
  if(nr != nc){
    warn <- sprintf("the data does not have an equal numbers of rows (%d) and columns (%d)", nr, nc)
    warning(warn)
  }
  if(out == "matrix"){
    combn(nr, n, \(i){
      combn(nc, n, \(j) x[i, j])
    })
  } else {
    combn(nr, n, \(i){
      combn(nc, n, \(j) as.data.frame(x[i, j]), simplify = FALSE)
    }, simplify = FALSE)
  }
}

m <- matrix(1:25, nrow = 5)
sub_df(m, 2)
sub_df(m[-1,], 2)        # gives a warning
sub_df(m, 2, "matrix")
sub_df(m, 2, "list")     # gives an error
```